# Interview riddle: A lovely place where ohm law is checked every day + you can feel the grapes (without the first letter)

Tags: riddle, wordplay

A lovely place where ohm law is checked every day + you can feel the grapes (without the first letter).

Clue:

> You can also find there gold… (The golden state)

What I came up until now is that the answer is a place in California.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Ohm's law - I = V/R, used in electricity. Not sure if that's any help.

Comment: We interpreted the ohm law as water fall.. (not sure)

Comment: Well, waterfalls are often used to explain the underlying principles: http://chemwiki.ucdavis.edu/Analytical_Chemistry/Electrochemistry/Voltage,_Amperage_and_Resistance_Basics

Comment: A lovely place where you can feel the grapes, without the first letter ? Nope D:

Comment: A lovely place where you can eel the grapes?

Comment: Well, let's just hope the first letter to ignore isn't the 'g' from grapes....

Comment: Where was the interview? City? Company? Could be a clue.

Comment: Broadcom company.

Comment: Can you give any more context clues? Where are they located? What was the position? Was the riddle told to your or spoken? Were you given the clues *as* an additional clue or was that part of what you were originally given?

Comment: Could be anything. How about "a supermarket"? At least my local dealer has [Goldwasser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Goldwasser) in stock, and loose grapes, and every morning, they switch on the light. If Ohm's law has been invalidated during the night, all bulbs should burn through. (Hasn't happened yet, though.)

Comment: What's an "interview riddle"?

Comment: @dennisdeems A job interview question used by companies with a disfunctional recruitment process.

Comment: Irvine
I was interview for Broadcom - this is the headquarters location.

Answer (score 8):

It's probably

> [Irvine, Califonia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irvine,_California)

Ohm's law:

> I*R = V (***IRV***)

The part about the grapes:

> Vine - first letter = ***INE***

Result:

> Irv+ine

The clue you gave is probably just referencing:

> California is the golden state, as you thought. I couldn't find any obvious information about a gold mine or anything in the area.

The biggest clue:

> You mentioned the interview was with Broadcom, which is located in Irvine.

Comment: Not solution-related: In my opinion, it's kind of an inelegant stretch that would be fine as a casual puzzle, but I hope they didn't take it too seriously as an interview riddle.

Comment: It might not be a reference to a specific gold mine, but rather the historical gold rush that led people to California.

Answer (score 4):

Based off of your posting on another website: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=5114718433837056

I gathered the name of the company is Micron. A quick look at wikipedia shows Micron was founded in Boise, Idaho: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Micron_Technology

I also noticed they work with "many forms of semiconductor devices, including dynamic random-access memory, flash memory, and solid-state drives." - Hence the first hint towards a "place where ohms law is checked every day".

I also found that if you remove the "B" from the from the front of "Boise" -  you get "Oise" - an area of France that according to Google has many winerys and wine tasting tours. A nod towards "you can feel the grapes (without the first letter)."

On the clue you gave - I think the (Golden State) in parenthesis is your inclusion since you say you have guessed California so far. However I can't really find a direct connection to Boise and gold except that some gold medalists come from Boise in different sports and that Idaho in general seems to be popular for gold panning. There is also a city in Idaho named Golden - how that relates to Boise I am not sure.

Probably a stretch but it was my lunch break and I wanted to give it a shot. I really do hope you will be honest with the interviewer if you get an answer from the internet rather than passing it off as your own since it appears you are asking on multiple sites. A lot of times these questions are more to see how you think rather than if you get the right answer. In fact it could even be a nonsensical riddle just to see what you come up with.

Comment: Gold is used in electronics, due to its conducting properties. Might be a reference to that.